# JQuery Datepicker date range and months

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, uidatepicker

I would like to show number of months shown based on the number of selectable days.

So an example would be that if I have 15 days to select from and the date starts from today (23/04/2013) I would like only April and May to be shown as number of months shown to select from.

Similarly, if the number of selectable days 60 I would like to show April, May and June as the  the number of months shown.

So in essence how do I make number of months shown is conditional to the number of selectable days?

Many thanks in advance.

my plugin

```
$.fn.showCalendar = function(options){
    var defaults ={
        selector : "#date-selector",
        calendarIcon : "./images/icons/calendar.gif",
        numberOfSelectableDays : "+60D",
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        numberOfMonths : 3,
        daySelector : "#day",
        monthSelector : "#month",
        yearSelector : "#year"
    }

    var $this = $(this);
    var params = $.extend({},defaults, options);

    var getDateFromDropDowns = function(){
         var dateOnDropDowns =  new Date($(params.daySelector).val(),$(params.monthSelector).val(),$(params.yearSelector).val());
         return  dateOnDropDowns;
    }


    return $this.each(function(){
        $this.datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: params.calendarIcon,
            minDate: 0,
            maxDate: params.numberOfSelectableDays,
            dateFormat: params.dateFormat,
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            numberOfMonths: params.numberOfMonths,
            setDate : getDateFromDropDowns,
            onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
                $(params.yearSelector).val(dateText.split('/')[2]);
                $(params.daySelector).val(dateText.split('/')[0]);
                $(params.monthSelector).val(dateText.split('/')[1]);
            }
        });
    });
},
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you already tried?

Comment: I will suggest to show code related to Question here. instead of link to other question

Comment: Edited and added to the page :)

Answer (score 0):

Updates as per comment
To Update number of Months to be shown at a time on screen
you can use this code o calculate the number of months

```
var d = new Date(); 
var n = d.getDate(); 
var total=n+60; 
var numberOfMonthsVal=Math.floor(total/30)+1;
```

and in `$this.datepicker({` use `numberOfMonths:numberOfMonthsVal`

---

With JQuery UI Date Picker

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" }); // Thiw will sow the dates Today -20 to today + 1 Month +10 days
});
```

In Your case you want to show say next 60 days from today?

```
$(function() {
    var day=new Date();
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: day, maxDate: (day+60) }); 
});
```

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

So in your plugin when you are calling `$this.datepicker({` pass below values

```
        minDate: myDate,
        maxDate: (myDate+60)
```

where `mydate is actual Date object like var mydate=new Date();`

Comment: It's the number of Months shown to the user on the same screen next to each other at a given point that I'm after. I think you may have misunderstood the question. Thanks for looking though :)

Comment: Then you can clauclate the `numberOfMonths` something like this... 
`var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDate();
var total=n+60; // 60 o 15 the days you want to add
var numberOfMonths=(total/30)+1;
`

Comment: I ended up writing this myself using few custom functions. Thanks for you help :)